# Creating lines along calibrated polyline from M values in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, linear-referencing, m-values

I have an M-value enabled polyline feature class and from-to M-values of lines.
The polyline is already calibrated.
Is there any way to create line along the calibrated polylines or get that segment of line using (from-to) M-values in ArcMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the help file for the [Create Routes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/create-routes.htm) tool. If your existing polylines are attributed with FROM and TO fields you can use these to calibrate the polyline and insert M along the polyline in a new FeatureClass. Review the Syntax section of the tool.

Comment: The line is already calibrated and measured values are extracted from that. Right now I have measured values i.e. from to. Do I need to recalibrate the line?

Comment: If your line dataset is already calibrated, are you asking how to create lines along these calibrated routes using from and to values? If so look at the [make route event tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/make-route-event-layer.htm). If not you need to edit your question and add more detail, may be an image?